# Reposting a (mathematical) question that disappeared

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Yesterday I posted a comment on a recent math.SE question that interested me, suggesting a "perhaps.. fruitful" approach.  Later with a bit more insight I looked back and found the question had disappeared!

The purely mathematical nature of the question was not AFAIK open to doubt.  It seems most likely the user who posted the question decided to remove it.

However the question was so interesting that I'm tempted to rephrase and post it myself, but a few nagging doubts occur to me:

1. It might have been removed because it's known to be part of some online competition.
2. It might have been removed as a homework problem, either by the OP or a moderator.
3. There might have been a glitch in math.SE that caused the question to get unlinked.

Is it something I should ask a moderator about before reposting?

Comment: Is there some reason why you are keeping the identity of the question secret, thereby making it impossible for anyone to look into its disappearance?

Comment: No, @GerryMyerson, obviously I cannot provide a link to the Q itself and I don't recall the asker's username.  If moderators had access to the deleted posts from yesterday, they might be able to cross-reference my comment (from which I quoted a couple of key words above).  The Q was about an $m \times m$ square grid, more specifically about pairing adjacent horizontal and vertical edges.  I believe the word "grid" appeared in the Q title...

Comment: I've tried to find it --- no luck --- guess it's a job for the mods, after all. Nothing like it showed up on my "Tools" page, under "deleted".

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: According to [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/people-who-ask-homework-questions-and-then-remove-them#comment16396_4277) the post deleted by OP don't appear there.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry and Martin, for the helpful replies.  As it turns out the browser history allowed me to recover the Q identifier (238717) and the presumed poster's username.  I'll try to bring it up with a moderator.  The previous discussion pointed out by @MartinSleziak is especially relevant.

Comment: It may be that someone has reposted this question --- see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239970/splitting-lattice-segments

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Hmmm, I don't want to seem paranoid, but following that link gives me that the Q was "removed... for reasons of moderation".

Comment: No need for paranoia --- I flagged it for moderator attention, and a moderator removed it for the duration of the contest. It hadn't attracted any answers or comments, other than mine.

Comment: @BillDubuque decided to [undelete the 2nd post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6611/3111), although he did put a note at the top regarding the "contested" nature of the Q.